# When you click this round button a box padding appear how can i remove it?

Tags: javascript, html, css

When you click this round button a box padding appears how can I remove it?

The intentions of the button is to add a display none to the button, but during click down weird padding appear, any idea how can I stop that form happening.

```js
const boton = document.getElementById('btnEmpezar')

const amarillo = document.getElementById('do')



boton.addEventListener('click', (event) => console.log(event))

function hideButton() {

  boton.classList.add('hide')

}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.gameboard {
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: 300px;
  height: 260px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 5%;
  position: relative;
}

.polen {
  position: absolute;
  border: 3px solid black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: blueviolet;
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
  top: calc(0% - 50px);
  left: calc(-20% - 200px);
}

.box {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
  border-radius: 5%;
}

.uno {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.767);
  position: relative;
}

.dos {
  background-color: rgb(49, 122, 55);
}

.tres {
  background-color: rgb(213, 224, 46);
  position: relative;
}

.cuatro {
  background-color: rgb(194, 13, 13);
}

.petado {
  width: 130px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 3px solid black;
  background-color: rgb(252, 255, 55);
  display: flex;
  align-self: flex-end;
  border-top-left-radius: 60%;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 50%;
}

.petado.light {
  background-color: rgb(252, 253, 201);
}

.petado.dark {
  background-color: rgb(195, 197, 48);
}

.petaun {
  width: 130px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 3px solid black;
  display: flex;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 50%;
  border-top-right-radius: 60%;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
  background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.petaun.light {
  background-color: rgb(255, 129, 129);
}

.petaun.dark {
  background-color: rgb(177, 0, 0);
}

.petatre {
  width: 130px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 3px solid black;
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  background-color: rgb(79, 255, 88);
  border-bottom-right-radius: 60%;
  border-top-left-radius: 50%;
}

.petatre.light {
  background-color: rgb(198, 253, 201);
}

.petatre.dark {
  background-color: rgb(67, 204, 74);
}

.petacua {
  width: 130px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 3px solid black;
  display: flex;
  background-color: blue;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 60%;
  border-top-right-radius: 50%;
}

.petado.light {
  background-color: rgb(138, 138, 255);
}

.petado.dark {
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 211);
}

.polen {
  position: absolute;
  border: 10px solid black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  width: 45px;
  height: 45px;
  top: calc(50% - 33px);
  left: calc(50% - 33px);
}

.polen.light {
  background-color: rgb(133, 127, 127)
}

.polen.dark {
  background-color: rgb(207, 205, 205);
}

.boton {
  position: absolute;
  border: 5px solid rgb(255, 255, 255);
  color: aliceblue;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: rgb(27, 26, 26);
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  top: calc(50% - 31px);
  left: calc(50% - 30px);
  z-index: 1;
  font-size: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: right;
}

.boton.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8
        
        ">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>

</head>

<body>
  <div class="gameboard">
    <div class="box uno light">
      <div class="petaun" data-color="red"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="box dos light">
      <div id="do" class="petado" data-color="yallow"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="box tres light">
      <div class="petatre" data-color="green"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="box cuatro light">
      <div class="petacua" data-color="yallow"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="polen" data-color="polen"></div>
    <button id="btnEmpezar" class="boton" onclick="hideButton()">Empezar!</button>

  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What's with the _lorem ipsum_?  May I recommend that you take the time to turn this example (and especially any future questions you ask) into a runnable snippet and strip it down to a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the outline: 0 to prevent it

```
.boton:focus{
  outline:0;
}
```

But I think you should add something else to make sure when user click it and see it works for that I add hover state to let's user see this is clickable

```
.boton:hover{
  border: 5px solid rgb(200, 200, 200);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
        <head>
          <meta charset="UTF-8
    
    ">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <title>Document</title>
    <style>

  body{
    margin: 0;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
  }
.gameboard{
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: 300px;
  height: 260px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 5%;
  position: relative;
  
}
.polen{
  position: absolute;
  border: 3px solid black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: blueviolet;
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
  top: calc(0% - 50px);
             left: calc(-20% - 200px);
  
}

.box{
 box-sizing: border-box;
  
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px  solid black ;
  display: flex;
 margin: 0;
 border-radius: 5%;
}
.uno{
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.767);
  position: relative;
}
.dos{
  background-color:  rgb(49, 122, 55);
  
}

.tres{
  background-color: rgb(213, 224, 46) ;
  position: relative;
}

.cuatro{
  background-color: rgb(194, 13, 13);
}

.petado{
  width: 130px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 3px solid black;
  background-color: rgb(252, 255, 55);
  display: flex;
  align-self: flex-end;
  border-top-left-radius: 60%;
  border-bottom-right-radius:50% ;


}

.petado.light{
  background-color: rgb(252, 253, 201);
  
}

.petado.dark{
  background-color:rgb(195, 197, 48);
}

.petaun{
  width: 130px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 3px solid black;
  display: flex;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 50% ;
  border-top-right-radius: 60%;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
  background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
  position: absolute;
   bottom:0;
   right:0;

}

.petaun.light{
  background-color: rgb(255, 129, 129);
}


.petaun.dark{
  background-color: rgb(177, 0, 0);
}

.petatre{
  width: 130px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 3px solid black;
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  background-color: rgb(79, 255, 88);
  border-bottom-right-radius: 60%;
  border-top-left-radius: 50%;
}

.petatre.light{
  background-color: rgb(198, 253, 201);
}


.petatre.dark{
  background-color: rgb(67, 204, 74);
}

.petacua{
  width: 130px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 3px solid black;
  display: flex;
  background-color: blue;
  border-bottom-left-radius:60% ;
  border-top-right-radius: 50%;

}

.petado.light{
  background-color: rgb(138, 138, 255);
  
}

.petado.dark{
  background-color:rgb(0, 0, 211);
}

.polen{
  position:absolute;
  border: 10px solid black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  width: 45px;
  height: 45px;
  top: calc(50% - 33px);
  
  left:calc(50% - 33px);

}

.polen.light{
  background-color: rgb(133, 127, 127)
  
}

.polen.dark{
  background-color:rgb(207, 205, 205);
}

 

.boton{
  
  position:absolute;
  border: 5px solid rgb(255, 255, 255);
  color: aliceblue;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: rgb(27, 26, 26);
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  top: calc(50% - 31px);
  
  left:calc(50% - 30px);
  z-index: 1;
  font-size: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: right;
}

.boton.hide{
  display: none;
}
.boton:hover{
  border: 5px solid rgb(200, 200, 200);
}
.boton:focus{
  outline:0;
}
</style>

</head>
<body>
  <div class="gameboard">
    <div class="box uno light" >
      <div class="petaun" data-color="red" ></div>
    </div>
    <div class="box dos light">
      <div id="do" class="petado" data-color="yallow"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="box tres light" >
      <div class="petatre" data-color="green"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="box cuatro light" >
      <div class="petacua" data-color="yallow"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="polen" data-color="polen"></div>
    <button id="btnEmpezar" class="boton" onclick="hideButton()">Empezar!</button>

  </div>

  <script>

 const boton = document.getElementById('btnEmpezar')

  const amarillo =  document.getElementById('do')



    boton.addEventListener('click', (event) => console.log(event))

  function hideButton(){
    
  boton.classList.add('hide')

  }

 

 

  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
button:focus {
    outline: none;
}
```

It removes the outline when you click on it (the ":focus").